# How do I set a file's mtime in epoch format?

Tags: shell, timestamps, touch

I know how to *get* a file's mtime in epoch format:

```
stat --format=%Y <file>
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to *set* a file's mtime in epoch format. The touch(1) man page appears to only accept a "timestamp" value (more-or-less fixed format which uses months, days, hours, minues, etc) or a "mostly free format human readable date string".

Is there another utility I should be looking into?

Thanks.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At least in the GNU world:

```
touch --date=@1403970787 file
```

Like with `date`.

Answer (score 2):

With the `touch` command from GNU coreutils (i.e. on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin), look at the [full manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html#touch-invocation) (usually available locally in info format) for the documentation of [date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats). [Epoch dates](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html#Seconds-since-the-Epoch) are indicated with the prefix `@`:

```
touch -d @1234567890 foo
```

This also works with BusyBox (at least on some systems, it might depend on compilation options).

With *BSD, I don't think you can do this with `touch` alone, but you can call `date` to format the epoch time into a format that `touch` accepts.

```
touch -d "$(date -r 1234567890 +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" foo
```

POSIX notoriously lacks ways to manipulate epoch dates. You can [use perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139675).

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -e 'utime (stat($_))[8], time(), $_ for @ARGV' file1 file2 ...
```

This will change mtime of all files in `@ARGV`. `(stat($_))[8]` is atime of file.

`utime` can receive list of files, if you don't care about changing atime, you can try:

```
 $ perl -e '$t = time(); utime $t, $t, @ARGV' file1 file2 ...
```

**Note**

`utime` depends on C runtime library and filesystem is using. see more in `perldoc -f utime` and `perldoc perlport`.